# Calculate the solution set of this system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

> Calculate the solution set of this system of equations in
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times
> \mathbb{Z}_{3}$
>
> $$I: x_{1}+2x_{2}+x_{4}=2$$
>
> $$II: 2x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+2x_{4}=0$$
>
> $$III: 2x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=0$$
>
> $$IV:x_{1}=1$$

It is important for me to understand the meaning of $Z_{3}$. I think it means that we could add a $\text{ mod }3$ in every equation which has been ignored in this example, right?

So actually it should be saying $\text{ I: }(x_{1}+2x_{2}+x_{4}) \text{ mod } 3=2$ instead, right?

If so, how would you solve this because this modulus will make things completely different :o I could solve it if there wasn't this modulus.. or maybe we can leave it away?

Comment: You've missed two solutions, namely $(1,2,2,0)$ and $(1,0,2,1)$.

Comment: How did you get these solutions? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve it in exactly the same way as you would if you worked over one of the usual fields, such as $\Bbb R$. Namely, you could write it in matrix form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\bar 1 & \bar 2 & \bar 0 & \bar 1 \\
\bar 2 & \bar 1 & \bar 1 & \bar 2 \\
\bar 0 & \bar 2 & \bar 1 & \bar 1 \\
\bar 1 & \bar 0 & \bar 0 & \bar 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \bar 2 \\ \bar 0 \\ \bar 0 \\ \bar 1 \end{pmatrix} ,$$

notice that the determinant of the system matrix is $\bar 0$ (meaning that the system has multiple solutions), then noticing that the lower left $3 \times 3$ determinant is non-zero, choosing $x_1, x_2, x_3$ as main unknowns and $x_4$ as a parameter and solve the new $3 \times 3$ system using Cramer's method. The last step would be to give $x_4$ the values $\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar2$ and write down the corresponding values for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. This would be an algorithmic approach.

It is more convenient though, in this very specific problem, to use a shortcut: since we are already given that $x_1 = \bar 1$, replace it in all the other equations to get a new system

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray}
\bar 2 x_2 + x_4 &=& \bar 1 \\
x_2 + x_3 + \bar 2 x_4 &=& - \bar 2 = \bar 1 \\
\bar 2 x_2 + x_3 + x_4 &=& \bar 0 .
\end{eqnarray} \right.$$

Subtracting the first equation from the third gives us $x_3 = - \bar 1 = \bar 2$. Replacing this in the new system, the first and third equation will now coincide, so we write only one of them, in order to get yet another system

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray}
\bar 2 x_2 + x_4 &=& \bar 1 \\
x_2 + \bar 2 x_4 &=& \bar 2 .
\end{eqnarray} \right.$$

Finally, this means that from the first equation of this last system we may obtain $x_4 = \bar 1 - \bar 2 x_2 = \bar 1 + x_2$ (we cannot do better because this small system has determinant $\bar 0$, meaning that its solution is not unique), which means that the general solution of the original system is $(\bar 1, x_2, \bar 2, \bar 1 + x_2)$. Since $\Bbb Z _3 = \{ \bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2 \}$, for each value of $x_2$ in this list of elements we shall obtain a corresponding solution of the original system; namely, these will be

$$(\bar 1, \bar 0, \bar 2, \bar 1), \quad (\bar 1, \bar 1, \bar 2, \bar 2), \quad (\bar 1, \bar 2, \bar 2, \bar 0) .$$

Comment: Very big thanks for this answer and your time! But why you wrote: $$x_{2}+x_{3}+2x_{4}=-2=1$$, so how you know $$-2=1$$?

Comment: @berndgr: That thing encodes the fact that $-2 \pmod 3 = 1 \pmod 3$. If you don't know modular arithmetic, though, how come you have to solve such problems?

Comment: Great answer, too bad I cannot pay more repuation because this answer is worth more, I have learned a lot from it and it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding (I) and (II) immediately gives $x_3=2$. Then (I) reads $1+2x_2+x_4=2$ which is $x_4=1-2x_2=1+x_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Maybe you can explain a bit more detailled? :P